# Are we able to freeze the first lane in react-trello?

Tags: reactjs, trello

My react-trello board has 9 lanes. My screen shows 6 lanes at any given time and I am needing to scroll to the right to see the last 3. The first lane is important and I would like it to ALWAYS show even after scrolling to right. Are we able to freeze the first lane (make it stay in place even after scroll)?